# manually fix vulnerability with npm audit

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 11 vulnerabilities that I have to sort out manually and can't use `npm audit fix`

Based on [this page](https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/337) there's no remediation, however the package's page says the issue has been patched in the [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval).

Doing `npm update` or placing `"safe-eval": "^0.4.1",` in my package.json doesn't resolve the vulnerability.

How can patched vulnerability be fixed in my project ?